# Transaction Check Error: file from install of oraclelinux-release-6:6Server-3.0.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel6

I am trying downgrade oracle linux 6.7 to 6.6

[root@xxxx ~]# yum downgrade redhat-release

I am getting an error that "Transaction Check Error: file /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY from install of oraclelinux-release-6:6Server-3.0.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package rhn-client-tools-1.0.0.1-32.0.4.el6.noarch"

Comment: Your machine is very confused.  It has components of both Red Hat Enterprise Linux and Oracle Unmentionable Linux, and, like matter and anti-matter, when you mix them things blow up.  I have no idea how you would even put that back together again.

Comment: So no way to get back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
yum install --downloadonly oraclelinux-release
find /var/cache/yum/ -type f -name "oraclelinux-release*rpm" \ 
   -exec rpm -Uvh --force {} \;
```

First command will download the package you want to install, but won't try to install it. Package will be saved under /var/cache/yum.

Second command will find the downloaded rpm, and force installing it.

To make your system sane again, you could do this afterwards:

```
rpm -e --nodeps rhn-client-tools
find /var/cache/yum/ -type f -name "oraclelinux-release*" \
  -exec rpm -Uvh --force {} \;
```

This will remove rhn-client-tools, which is obviously a part of RedHat installation and not Oracle Unbreakable Linux, and afterwards you'll install the oraclelinux-release package once more just in case removal of rhn-client-tools removed anything significant.

Note: do not do this without testing if you're not feeling comfortable with rpm/yum.